# forLoop except criteria is deleting whole row, which i do not want

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Let me start with the background: I have a Dataframe. It's a column of hyperlinks. I use a forLoop to extract the hyperlinks with an attribute target and add them to an appended column.

[Result of successful forLoop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeD9p.png)

now let me throw curveball: a blank/gap. let's say that there is a gap in the column and Source C is out of the picture – what happens to the forLoop then?

[Result of unwanted forLoop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDeOT.png)

what if instead of deleting the *entire* row, I want the forLoop to put a blank cell there? so that no data is being rearranged and Source C has a blank cell or NaN cell next to it. Does that make sense? What are my options? (also note that my print() function is not really working as I intend it to.) for what it's worth, ws.cell is an openpyxl operation that accesses a cell of an Excel sheet.

Here is the hard code just in case:

```
links = []
for i in range(2, ws.max_row + 1):  # 2nd arg in range() not inclusive, so add 1
    try:
        links.append(ws.cell(row=i, column=1).hyperlink.target)
    except AttributeError or NaN:
        print('nothing here')

df['link'] = pd.Series(links)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your input data, i.e. the input xlsx file and may not be able make a sure solution.  Anyway, have you tried the following?

```
...
except AttributeError or NaN:
    lists.append('')                      # still append a blank string to the list
    print('nothing here')
```